# Run series of commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, batch-processing

I have this JavaFX tool which generates bss files from css files.

```
javafxpackager -createbss -srcfiles love.css -outdir . -outfile love
```

The problem is that I have 20+ cs fiels and running the command every time for every css file is not a option. Can you tell me how I can automate this process with bat file. For example I want to get all css file and run the tool for every file. Can you help me to automate this process, please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 for %%a in (*.css) do (
    javafxpackager -createbss -srcfiles %%a -outdir . -outfile %%~na
 )
```

If you want to just run that from the command line, remove one of the %'s so %%a is %a, etc.